# How to do some reporting with Rails (with a dedicated DB)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting

In a Rails app, I am wondering how to build a reporting solution. I heard that I should use a separated database for reporting purposes but knowing that I will need to store a huge amount of data, I have a lot of questions :

- What kind of DBMS should I choose?
- When should I store data in the reporting database?
- Should the database schema of the production db and reporting db be identical?

I am storing basic data (information about users, about result of operations) and I will need for example to run a report to know how many user failed an operation during the previous month.

In now that it is a vague question, but any hint would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: We also have a lot of questions: what kind of data are you storing? What kind of reports do you need? Any other requirements?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I added information in the post, thanks

Comment: http://philip.greenspun.com/wtr/data-warehousing I'll just leave this here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Work Backwards

Start from what the end-users want for reporting or how they want to/should visualize data.  Once you have some concepts in mind, then start working backwards to how to achieve those goals.  Starting with the assumption that it should be a replicated copy in an RBDMS excludes several reasonable possibilities.

### Making a Real-time Interface

If users are looking to aggregate values (counts, averages, etc.) on the fly (per web request), it would be worthwhile looking into replicating the master down to a reporting database if the SQL performance is acceptable (and stays acceptable if you were to double the input data).  SQL engines usually do a great job aggregation and scale pretty far.  This would also give you the capability to join data results together and return complex results as the users request it.

Just remember, replication isn't easy or without it's own set of problems.

This'll start to show signs of weakness in the hundreds of millions of rows range with normalized data, in my experience.  At some point, inserts fight with selects on the same table enough that both become exceptionally slow (remember, replication is still a stream of inserts).  Alternatively, indexes become so large that storage I/O is required for rekeying, so overall table performance diminishes.

### Batching

On the other hand, if reporting falls under the scheme of sending standardized reports out with little interaction, I wouldn't necessarily recommend backing to an RBDMS.  In this case, results are combined, aggregated, joined, etc. once.  Paying the overhead of RBDMS indexing and storage bloat isn't worth it.

Batch engines like [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org) will scale horizontally (many smaller machines instead of a few huge machines) so processing larger volumes of data is economical.

#### Batch to RBDMS or K/V Store

This is also a useful path if a lot of computation is needed to make the records more meaningful to a reporting engine.  Alternatively, records could be denormalized before storing them in the reporting storage engine.  The denormalized or simple results would then be shipped to a key/value store or RBDMS to make reporting easier and achieve higher performance at the cost of latency, compute, and possibly storage.

### Personal Advice

Don't over-design it to start with.  The decisions you make on the initial implementation will probably all change at some point.  However, design it with the current and near-term problems in mind.  Also, benchmarks done by others are not terribly useful if your usage model isn't exactly the same as theirs; benchmark your usage model.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I am also having trouble to understand when I should build my reporting database: should I use a cron every night/week that is consolidating all the data of the previous last/week from the main db to the reporting db? Is it a good practice or something else should be done?

Comment: A finite answer is pretty tough but I would suggest this guideline.  Update as often as you can (more accurate reporting) but avoid impacting execution of inserts into the master database.  Generally, slowing result generation into the master database is more costly to a business than less accurate or more latent reporting results.

Comment: So in other words your are suggesting me to find a moment when the master database in not used too much?

Comment: Either a low period of activity to do a large sync (off hours) or smaller chunks throughout the day if it doesn't disrupt operations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to to use some pre-build reporting services than to manually write out if you need a large set of reports.

You might want to look at Tableau http://www.tableausoftware.com/ and other available.

Database .. Yes it should be a separate seems safer , plus reporting is generally for old and consolidated data.. you live data might be too large to perform analysis on.

Database type -- > have to choose based on the reporting services used , though I think mongo is not supported by any of the reporting services , mysql is preferred.

If there are only one or two reports you could just build them on rails